# How to change the contents of the datacursor when using mpldatacursor

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a simple code written to plot the red circles.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpldatacursor import datacursor

lines = plt.plot([1,2,3,4], [1,4,9,16], 'ro')
plt.axis([0, 6, 0, 20])
datacursor(lines)
plt.show()
```

The above code is generating pyplot as follows:
[image]

My question is when I click on the red mark of the plot, how can I change the label (x, y) to custom label from the appeared popup?

Is it possible to show this pop up only for few second?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the [`formatter` kwarg](https://github.com/joferkington/mpldatacursor/#controlling-the-displayed-text) to customize the displayed data. For example to force the x and y values to both be integers, we can do something like the following:

```
datacursor(lines, formatter='x: {x:.0f}\ny: {y:.0f}'.format)
```

You can use any custom formatter to change the displayed text in any way including the labels themselves.

```
datacursor(lines, formatter='my_x: {x:.0f}\nmy_y: {y:.0f}'.format)
```

Rather than using `str.format` as shown above, you can even write an entire function to format your labels.

```
def myformatter(**kwarg):
    label = 'My custom label at point ({x:.0f}, {y:.0f})'.format(**kwarg)
    return label

datacursor(lines, formatter=myformatter)
```

Comment: Thank you. You were very quick. I was just modifying my question :)

Comment: Is it possible to make that pop up appear for few second only?

Comment: @nas Unfortunately that functionality isn't built into the data cursor that you're using. You would have to look into using a timer or something to make the cursor disappear. That may be worth asking in a different question since it's very different from modifying the label

Comment: Thank you very much @Suever